# Не работает ajaxstart

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть сайт на WP, на нем есть плагин ajax фильтра. Мне нужно добавить js события, которые будут срабатывать после срабатывания ajax. В документации плагина пишет, что это делается таким образом:

```
//detects the start of an ajax request being made
$(document).on("sf:ajaxstart", ".searchandfilter", function(){
  console.log("ajax start");
});
```

Но у меня при фильтрации ничего не происходит (то есть не выводится сообщение в консоли).
Пробовал даже так:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  console.log('AjaxStart');
})
```

Тоже ничего не выводит. Вопрос - как мне поставить события на срабатывания ajax запросов?

P.S. JQuery подключен(версия 3.5.1) и остальные элементы сайта на jquery работают без ошибок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил добавлением скрипта через анонимную функцию, но не в общий файл со скриптами, а в файл search-filter-build.min.js, который находится в папке в плагином ajax фильтра.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте обернуть в анонимную функцию.

```
(function($) {
  "use strict";

  $(document).on("sf:ajaxstart", ".searchandfilter", function() {
    console.log("ajax start");
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Пробовал. Также ничего не происходит